# Given the following properties, which points can have them (about elliptic, hyperbolic, parabolic, planar points)?

Tags: differential-geometry

Before giving any properties,

-elliptic $\equiv$ (E)

-hyperbolic $\equiv$ (H)

-parabolic $\equiv$ (P)

-plane $\equiv$ (L)

You substitute those with (X) below if they are true.

1. In any regular surface, if $p$ is an (X) point, then there is a neighbourhood of $p$ in the surface where the points around are (X).
2. There are regular surfaces with a point $p$ (X) where all of its neighbourhoods have points of a different type.

Which ones are true and why?

Comment: Your efforts so far?

Comment: I know that the second property works with planar points. The monkey's chair $(h(u,v)=u^3-3uv^2)$, with $\varphi(u,v) = (u,v,h(u,v))$, has a planar point in (0,0), and all its neighbourhoods have hyperbolic points. By that same example, we can also say that planar points don't work with the first property. Aside from that, I got nothing else.